# how to set label frame based on start time 10 am and end time 2 pm in uitableview ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

please tell me that how will create draw uilabel frame according to time like below image

how can I display the events with proper block adjustment?

I can find the overlapped events group,But not able to set the block adjustment. Ex:- I have below events

1)From 8:00 To 12:00 event A

2)From 8:00 To 9:00 event B

3)From 9:00 To 10:00 event C

4)From 10:00 To 11:00 event D

5)From 11:00 To 12:00 event E

should be display like below picture.

Thanks & Regards
yogesh sharma

Comment: you can use [NSDate date]; using this you dan able to retrieve current date and time both, and using date formatter you can separate both and use them individually, so you are able to access date as well as time both.

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(void)currentTime
{    
    //Get current time
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:now];
    NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
    NSString *am_OR_pm=@"AM";

    if (hour>12)
    {
        hour=hour%12;

        am_OR_pm = @"PM";
    }

    NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
    NSInteger second = [dateComponents second];
    [gregorian release];

    NSLog(@"Current Time  %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d %@", hour, minute, second,am_OR_pm]);
}
```

This function will get you the current time. Using this you can frame your Label

To create and frame a label you can use the following code...

```
UILabel *fromLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(91, 15, 10, 10)];
```